# Align one element of a container at the top left corner and the other at the bottom right using flexbox?

Tags: flexbox

[image]

The element in the image is styled using absolute positioning but when I resize the screen I have to slightly adjust the positioning of both the 'For Sale' element and the '$400,000' element so I am curious as to if there is a way to achieve the same layout using flexbox?

Here is my attempt (https://codepen.io/ob98/pen/eYVPJLJ)

```
<div class = 'container'>
  <p class='item1'>Top Left</p>
  <p class='item2'>Bottom Right</p>
</div>
```

css:

```
.container{
  display: flex;
  
  background: red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  color: white;
}

.item1{
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.item2{
  align-self: flex-end;
  justify-self: flex-end; /* If align-self moved this to the bottom  of the container vertically, I am thinking that this should move it to the end/right side of the container horizontally, but that is not working  */
}
```

Just went to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-self and saw that "In flexbox layouts, this property is ignored (more about alignment in Flexbox)", so I guess that explains why that is not working but I don't really understand why this property is being ignored... Anyway, is there a way to achieve this layout using flexbox or do I have to stick to absolute positioning? Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to `.container` the declaration `justify-content: space-between`, to make both your `p` go to the container edges, and that's done!

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  color: white;
}

.item1 {
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.item2 {
  align-self: flex-end;
  justify-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class = 'container'>
  <p class='item1'>Top Left</p>
  <p class='item2'>Bottom Right</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Will accept in six minutes, thank you! Now that I see this I feel like I should have been able to think of doing that myself, still trying to get a grip on flexbox. But appreciate the answer.

Comment: It's normal, sometimes, we can always forget things that we were suppose to remember, for being too obvious. Anyways, I am glad for being able to help, and thank you for the consideration! ^^

Answer (score 2):

Can be the answer but im not sure. When i ran it worked.

```css
.bg-flex {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url('https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/the-city-of-london-skyline-at-night-united-kingdom-picture-id1312550959');
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.for-sale {
  height: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.k-400 {
  height: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.example {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-flex">
  <div class="for-sale">
    <div class="example">

    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="k-400">
    <div class="example">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Adding justify-content to container and just using the item2 class like this would help.

```
.container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  color: white;
}

.item2{
  align-self: flex-end;  
}
```